# hibernate automatic type conversion

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hibernate is used as jpa provider.

I have an entity with `long` id:

```
@Id
@Column
private Long id;
```

But sometimes it may be queried with an `int` id:

```
int id = ...
entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, id)
```

And in this case entity is not found due to persisted and requested id type difference.

I could convert this `id` manually before passing to entity manager, but can hibernate perform such conversion internally?

Answer (score 1):

As per the best of my knowledge there's no such in-built mechanism in Hibernate. At the time of providing input, for example,

```
query.setParameter("abc", 5);
```

*5* will be considered as `int` only. If you want to pass it as `long` then you have to specify it like

```
query.setParameter("abc", 5L);
```

If you're passing any variable holding value, then you have to make sure that you convert that variable into `long` first and then pass it as a parameter.

Apart from this, you can also use

```
query.setLong("abc", 5L);
```

which will always make sure that the value you pass in, is `long` only.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
int z = 10;
        
long w = z;
System.err.println ("Value:" + w);
        
Long id = w;
System.err.println ("Value:" + id);
        
entityManager.find (MyEntity.class, id);
```